# Press enter on input text field to submit form

Tags: javascript, forms, dom, click, eventhandler

In my code I wish to be able to press enter and it to press my input button.
At the moment I am having no luck, any suggestions for my code? Thanks,

```
<form>

    <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Enter your name"> 

    <input type="button" id="button" value="enter">

</form>

<h1 id="output">Please Complete Form</h1>


<script>
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var input; 
var output;

button.addEventListener("click", clickHandler, false);
input.addEventListener("keypress", handle, false);

function clickHandler () {

    input = document.getElementById("input");
    output = document.getElementById("output");

    output.innerHTML = input.value; 

    }

function handle(e){
    if(e.keyCode==13){
    document.getElementById('button').click();
    }

    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You do not need to attach `keypress` event over input as it is a nature of input type text to submit the form when `enter` key is pressed.

*Note:* variable `input` is undefined when `addEventListener` is attched to it hence it produces error.

Try this:

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var input = document.getElementById("input");
button.addEventListener("click", clickHandler, false);

function clickHandler() {
  var output = document.getElementById("output");
  output.innerHTML = input.value;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Enter your name">
  <input type="button" id="button" value="enter">
</form>

<h1 id="output">Please Complete Form</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Enter your name" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { this.form.submit(); return false; }">
```

It may helpful.